# How to get featured image thumbnail to open larger version in attachment page?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a thumbnail of the featured image, which is linked to a larger version of the file. At the moment the file just opens in a standard browser window, but I would like it to open in an attachment page, but I can't figure out how to do it! Here is what I have at the moment:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
<div class="spudpictureandcontentwrapper">
<div class="illustration">
<?php  $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
</a></div> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm guessing I need to use a different function to pass a value to $large_image_url but can't work out which one.

Comment: well i guess you want to load that image in another tab it seems, if thats the case you can use target="_blank" attribute of anchor tag <a target="_blank" href="..... </a>

Comment: No, I'd want it in the same browser window so that the 'back' button is still available, the users will be quite old and I don't want to confuse them by taking them to a new window

Comment: At the moment the file just opens in a standard browser window, but I would like it to open in an attachment page<-- i dint get it. could you show me the link ?

Comment: http://tonywylie.co.uk/playground/potato/sharpes-express/

Comment: yes i see upon clicking image gets loaded in the same window.what you mean by "attachment page" ? do you want to open this image in thick box ? google thick box if you dont know about it .

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_attachment_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link)  to get a link to the attachment page or take a look at [`wp_get_attachment_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link)  which might simplify the process.

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
    <div class="spudpictureandcontentwrapper">
    <div class="illustration"><?php

        $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

        $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'large');

        $attachment_page = get_attachment_link($attachment_id);

        echo '<a href="' . esc_url($attachment_page) . '" title="' . esc_attr(get_the_title($attachment_id)) . '" >';

        the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>

        </a></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```